# MongoDB Fail Over with one address

Tags: mongodb, failover

I would like to know if it is at all possible to have mongodb fail overs only using a single address. I know replica sets are typically used for this while relying on the driver to make the switch over, but I was hoping there may be a solution out there that would allow one address or hostname to automatically change over when the mongodb instance was recognized as being down.

Any such luck? I know there are solutions for MySQL, but I haven't had much luck with finding something for MongoDB.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about re-assigning the IP address to another MongoDB instance if the first one fails?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why do you need such solution in the first place?

Comment: Yes, re-assigning of the IP. The idea would be to not have people that our connecting to our mongo instances to have to modify their code to contain other items in the replica set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, the driver holds a cache map of your replica set which it will query for a new primary when the set suffers an election. This map is refreshed once every so often however, if your application restarts (process is quit or something, or each request of PHP fork mode) then the driver has no choice but to refresh its map. At this point you will suffer connectivity problems.

Of course the best thing to do is to add a seedlist.

Using a single IP defies the redundancy that is in-built into MongoDB.